# What is the difference between HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated and HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated?

Tags: asp.net

What is the difference between HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated and HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated?

Which one would you use in which situation?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There's absolutely no difference. Checkout HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated implementation:

```
public bool IsAuthenticated
{
    get
    {
        return (((this._context.User != null) && 
                 (this._context.User.Identity != null)) &&
                 this._context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks like it's better to use HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated as it checks that User etc is not null.

Comment: Yeap, just need to make sure that HttpContext.Current.Request is not null.

Comment: Just some nit-picking, but then it's not exactly the same, since the calls are not interchangeable when the User or the User's Identity is null...

Comment: This means there is absolutely no reason to use `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` right?