# If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then... Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Ok so this problem is baffling me.  I have a custom class that all my pages inherit from

```
Public Class Page : Inherits Page
    Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'Display Admin Controls (Buttons) '
        If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
           'do some stuff '
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

But for some reason I'm getting this error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

on this line

```
If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
```

This only started happening in IIS7. I have been using this application in IIS6 for over a year without issue, and it's only since I migrated to IIS7 yesterday that this exception started.

Comment: Hi, does the exception only get thrown when the user is not logged in?

Comment: How are the authentication and membership tags configured in your web.config?

Comment: This only started happening in IIS7.  I have been using this application in IIS6 for over a year without issue, and it's only since I migrated to IIS7 yesterday that this exception started.

Comment: I wonder what's specifically different in IIS7 to cause this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
If User IsNot Nothing AndAlso 
   User.Identity IsNot Nothing AndAlso 
   User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
    'Do stuff
End If
```

Comment: Thanks John. I fixed it with that exact same stuff just before you answered, however I used nested If statements instead of AndAlso.  I think I'll change it to AndAlso for the clean factor. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use Request.IsAuthenticated instead of Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated.

`If Request.IsAuthenticated Then
    'Do stuff
 End If`

Internally Request.IsAuthenticated will verify that the User and it's Identity are set (not null). You could do the same in your code

Answer (score 0):

Use Request.IsAuthenticated instead. It checks for null user. See [What is the difference between HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated and HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379566).

Still, it is unclear why the behavior changed when you migrated.