# Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated returns object reference not set to instance of object

Tags: asp.net, authentication, nullreferenceexception

this works fine on my local site but as soon as i upload the site to my live server i get stem.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

on the first line of this:

```
if (!Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    pnlSignIn.Visible = true;
    pnlSignOut.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Can you attach the debugger, and then mouse-over the parts of that variable to see what is null? IE, check if Page is null, then is User is null, then if Identity is null.

Comment: Another question: Do you have a section in web.config for <authorization><allow users="?" /></authorization> etc etc? Could you edit your queston and include that section of web.config?

Comment: Check if the IIS authentication is the same and correct.

Comment: it can be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990433/if-user-identity-isauthenticated-then-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance

Answer (score 5):

You should use `Request.IsAuthenticated` instead of `Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`.

Internally `Request.IsAuthenticated` will verify that the User and it's Identity are set (not null). You could do the same in your code, but why bother.