# HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated throws System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

My code is simple like :

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Login ()
{
   if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
   {
      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
   }
   return View(new LoginModel());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionReslt Login (LoginModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.Email, model.Password))
              {
                  FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, false);

                  return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
              }
        }

    return View(model);
}
```

But my Log Service sometimes receive this error! `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

I don't think that the best practice to do null checks for every reference like :

```
if (User!=null && User.Identity!=null && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
```

Could you tell me why sometimes it is null ? and sometimes not ?
What is the best practice for it?

Comment: [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: `NullReferenceException` is a common situation for programmers. The link provided should help you understand the problem. Then use the debugger to find what/where/when you have a variable that is `null`.

Comment: He clearly knows what a NullReferenceException is and how to fix it.  That's not really his question.

Comment: yes Soner as Jonesy says , I know The `NullReferenceException` but I'm wondering why it is sometimes throwing the exception and sometimes not, I can do the null checks but I'm using `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` in many places and I don't want my code to be bad because of the null checks. And also it is always not null in debug mode so I never get this error.

Comment: @Figo, could you please show how do you authenticate your users? The problem might be there. Also you might be on a safe side using `Request.IsAuthenticated` instead of `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`.

Comment: @Andrei I've posted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use Request.IsAuthenticated instead of User.Identity.IsAuthenticated

[Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated returns object reference not set to instance of object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4519464/1173331)

> Internally Request.IsAuthenticated will verify that the User and it's
>   Identity are set (not null). You could do the same in your code, but
>   why bother.

User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is set when you invoke these methods :

```
FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(name, pwd)
```

Or

```
Membership.ValidateUser(name, pwd)
```

Or other Authentication mechanism methods that set cookies

Comment: Thanks I think this is the right way and I also read about the difference between Request.IsAuthenticated and User.Identity.IsAuthenticated