# Disallow a user to visit a page/URL without Logged In

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am new to ASP.net, newbie but I am learning it to my own! I am testing and learning the logged in and logged out functionality in ASP.NET. Actually my problem is that I have a simple page i.e. Default.aspx for login purpose as:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <h1>Please Sign in</h1>
    UserName:
    <asp:TextBox id="uname"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br/>
    Password:
    <asp:TextBox id="upass"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br/>
    <asp:Button id="but"  runat="server" text="signup" OnClick="but_Click"/>
    <br/>
    <asp:Label ID ="lblInformation" runat ="server" ForeColor ="Red"/>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

I am logging in as (Default.aspx.cs):

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    String name = null;
    String pass = null;

    protected void but_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        name = uname.Text;
        pass = upass.Text;
        if (name.Equals("admin")&&pass.Equals("admin"))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(name, false );
        }
    }
}
```

after my successful login; redirecting to Home.aspx as:

```
 <body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div>
       <h1>Hello User</h1>
        <asp:Button ID="but" OnClick="but_Click" text="signout" runat="server"/>
     </div>
   </form>
 </body>
```

and I am log out as Home.aspx.cs

```
 public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   }
   protected void but_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
      FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
   }
 }
```

***The Problem***
The Problem is that after logging in if I copy the Home.aspx page URL (the page I have landed after the login), and paste in the browser search bar and press enter, I am able to see it without I Have been logged in!

I mean I want my user to restrict landing on Home.aspx if hes not logged in any case!

So the question is how can i restrict my user to view Home.aspx page if he has not logged in because I can view the page even if I am not logged in just by copying the Home.aspx URl into browser!

Sorry for my english I am not from an english country I am just learning asp.net to my own.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Page_Load` event check for authorization.

```
if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
}
```

Comment: can you tell me the difference between User.Identity.IsAuthenticated vs Request.IsAuthenticated

Comment: @JavaNerd no difference. Refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379566/what-is-the-difference-between-httpcontext-current-request-isauthenticated-and-h

Comment: ok thanks for the help @CodetrixStudio it was what I was looking for thanks again!

Comment: you're welcome, don't forget to mark your question answered with the most helpful answer.

Comment: Although if I may just throw my 2  cents in - hard coding the login page is a sub-optimal approach. Using the FormsAuthentication class allows this to be configured externally from the page so if it changes in the future, you don't have to change anything in code. Edit: Assuming it's FormsAuthentication that's being used.

Comment: JavaNerd, please note @Nate222 point(+1 from me), this is just a sample code. Come up with a more solid logic of redirection in your web app for production.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the simplest way is inside the Home.aspx's Page_Load method, add

`if(!Request.IsAuthenticated) { FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLogin(); }`

Comment: can you tell me the difference between User.Identity.IsAuthenticated vs Request.IsAuthenticated

Comment: @Java Nerd - Request.IsAuthenticated works regardless of the authentication scheme being used eg. FormsAuthentication, WindowAuth, etc. Depending on your requirements, it's usually a more future-proof approach. EDIT: Hey, I learned something. As per CodetrixStudio's link, it appears that they're functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Let ASP.Net do the work for you; you can control this through web.config.

You can add the following to the `<system.web>` section:

```
  <!-- Specify that only authenticated users are allowed to access pages by default. 
   Those that anonymous users can access will be specified separately. -->
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
```

Then, you can add the following entry to allow non-logged in users access to default.aspx:

```
<!-- Specify those files that all users can access, even if they aren't logged in -->
<location path="Default.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```