# ASP.Net MVC 3 Redirect UnAuthorized User not to loginUrl

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, redirect, asp.net-membership, roles, unauthorized

i have a project using ASP.Net MVC3 and using membership for roles. i use authorize in every controller. 
eg:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    public ActionResult Index(string q, int i)
    {
      return View(model);
    }
```

if someone doesnt have role for administrator, then it will redirect to login page by default. how to change it,so it will redirect  into Views/Shared/UnAuthorize.cshtml ? or maybe if someone doesnt have role for administrator, it will show message box (alert) ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just change the page that have to be shown in the web.config (check that the route exists)

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/UnAuthorize" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

If you, instead, want to redirect to a specific path for every roles you can extend the AuthorizeAttribute with your own. Something like this (not tested, I write this to give you an idea)

```
public class CheckAuthorize : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public Roles[] Roles { get; set; }
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
    //Your code to get the user
    var user = ((ControllerBase)filterContext.Controller).GetUser();

    if (user != null)
    {
      foreach (Role role in Roles)
      {
        if (role == user.Role)
          return;
      }
    }      
    RouteValueDictionary redirectTargetDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();
    if user.Role==Role.Administrator
    {
      redirectTargetDictionary.Add("action", "Unauthorized");
      redirectTargetDictionary.Add("controller", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
      redirectTargetDictionary.Add("action", "Logon");
      redirectTargetDictionary.Add("controller", "Home");
    }
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(redirectTargetDictionary);
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution will result in redirect to UnAuthorized page both for unauthenticated and unautorized requestes

Answer (score 24):

i solved my problem. i only do this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class MyAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
   protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
   {
     //you can change to any controller or html page.
     filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/cpanel/roles/unauthorize");

   }
 }
```

and apply MyAuthorize to class or action:

```
[MyAuthorize]
public class AdminController :Controller
{
}
```

thats it.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can inherit from `AuthorizeAttribute` and override `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` which is responsible for redirection of unauhorized/unauthenticated requests. i think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238437/why-does-authorizeattribute-redirect-to-the-login-page-for-authentication-and-aut) will be helpful to you

Comment: the question i referred to contains the example code. if there is problem plz let me know

Answer (score 1):

My own version, based on ntep vodka's:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if(IsUserAuthenticated(filterContext.HttpContext)) 
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Account/InvalidRole");
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }

    private bool IsUserAuthenticated(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        return context.User != null && context.User.Identity != null && context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }
}
```

This way I get standard redirect to login page for not authenticated users, and custom redirect for users that are authenticated but don't have the appropriate role for the action.

Answer (score 1):

The code below helped and here is the reference in stackoverflow
[ASP.NET MVC 4 custom Authorize attribute - How to redirect unauthorized users to error page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284729/asp-net-mvc-4-custom-authorize-attribute-how-to-redirect-unauthorized-users-to)

```
public class CustomAuthorize: AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if(!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new
            RouteValueDictionary(new{ controller = "Error", action = "AccessDenied" }));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this method and it is very easy to implement.

[Securing Asp.net MVC3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx)

Change your default route to logon page in global.asax