# Show views based on authentication status in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

If user is logged in I want to show my department view, if not logged in want to show login page. I have tried something like this inside my `RouteConfig`

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
          if (HttpContext.Current.User==null)
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
              name: "Default",
              url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
              defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
        }
        else
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
             name: "Default",
             url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Department", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
               );
        }

    }
```

But this one always loads login page at startup.Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?
Note: I am using [Asp.net Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity) for this application

Comment: RegisterRoutes is not executed per call, but once per application startup.

Comment: @RoyDictus Is there any alternative available to do what I want?

Comment: This article on MSDN may be of interest to you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/20/building-a-simple-todo-application-with-asp-net-identity-and-associating-users-with-todoes.aspx

Comment: If you create a new MVC application from a template in Visual Studio 2013, you'll pretty much what you need. And don't check `HttpContext.Current.User` for null. It is incorrect and will give you wrong results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `HttpContext.Current.User==null` logic would go in the controller, not your route registration

Note- the correct call is `Request.IsAuthenticated`

Assuming you have an action method like this:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
  if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
    return new RedirectResult("toLoginPage")
  else
    return new View("loggedInView");
}
```

However, I *believe* the `[Authorize]` attribute could be what you want in your use case: *(note - having re-read the question, this may not be accurate, as you want to return a different view based on login status)*

```
[Authorize]
public ViewResult ShowPerson(int id)
{
    return new View("loggedInView");
}
```

And in your web.config, something like

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" />
</authentication>
</system.web>
```

In this particular instance, with the `[Authorize]` attribute above the action method, if the user is not logged in, they'd be redirected to log in.

Comment: You are technically correct,But What I want is exactly reverse of this. Want my startup page to be set for Login, and if user is logged in redirect to home page

Comment: you could register the Authorize attribute in the Global filters - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx

Comment: @Alex in Identity framework `FormsAuthentication` should be disabled in `web.config`. But everything else is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Create your own Authorization attribute:

```
public class CustomAuthorize: AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new
            RouteValueDictionary(new{ controller = "Error", action = "AccessDenied" }));
        }
    }
}
```

Then add **[CustomAuthorize]** to your controller and change the route it points to.

This was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13292334/537674)

Comment: this way an additional browser redirect would occur

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with route constraints:

```
public class DelegateConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private readonly Func<HttpContextBase, bool> _isMatch;

    public DelegateConstraint(Func<HttpContextBase, bool> isMatch)
    {
        _isMatch = isMatch;
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        return _isMatch(httpContext);
    }
}

public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "CustomAuth1",
            url: "AuthArea/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Department", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { auth = new DelegateConstraint(httpContext => !httpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated) }
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "CustomAuth2",
            url: "AuthArea/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { auth = new DelegateConstraint(httpContext => httpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated) }
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

In this example the ~/AuthArea url will be resolved by Account or Department controller depending on the Request.IsAuthenticated property.

UPDATE:
This way you get a complete routing capability, but still need to specify the correct controller:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Context dependent link", "Index", @Request.IsAuthenticated ? "Account" : "Department")
```

This link would always be rendered as:

```
<a href="/AuthArea">Context dependent link</a>
```