# Role based authorization redirect URL for one controller

Tags: c#, redirect, asp.net-core, .net-core

Im using role based authorization and it works fine, but for one controller I want a different redirect url than the default one for one controller. My current code:

```
[Authorize(Roles = nameof(EIdentityType.Support))]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
      //CLASS METHODS
}
```

This redirects the user to

```
/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fadmin
```

However I want the user (for this specific controller so not for other controllers) to be redirected to

```
/admin/login
```

I found examples for asp.net mvc-4 which explains how to do [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284729/asp-net-mvc-4-custom-authorize-attribute-how-to-redirect-unauthorized-users-to) but the example wont work for .net core because in .net core the method `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` cant be overriden (it does not exist in .net core `AuthorizeAttribute`).

How can I set a custom redirect URL for a specific controller in .net core when using role based authorization?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4890) discussion, authorization redirects are handled by authentication middleware.

For example, if cookie authentication is used you could override `CookieAuthenticationEvents.OnRedirectToAccessDenied` method to set custom redirect URL depending on request URL:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToAccessDenied = RedirectToAccessDenied,
        OnRedirectToLogin = ...
        OnRedirectToLogout = ...
        OnRedirectToReturnUrl = ...
    }
});
```

Implementation (check `CookieAuthenticationOptions` [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/Events/CookieAuthenticationEvents.cs#L57) for the default one):

```
private async Task RedirectToAccessDenied(CookieRedirectContext context)
{
    if (IsAjaxRequest(context.Request))
    {
        //default path
        context.Response.Headers["Location"] = context.RedirectUri;
        context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
    }
    else if (context.Request.Path.Value.Equals("/Foo/Bar"))
    {
        //custom
        context.Response.Redirect("http://google.com");
    }
    else
    {
        //default path
        context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
    }
}

private static bool IsAjaxRequest(HttpRequest request)
{
    if (!string.Equals(request.Query["X-Requested-With"], "XMLHttpRequest", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        return string.Equals(request.Headers["X-Requested-With"], "XMLHttpRequest", StringComparison.Ordinal);

    return true;
}
```