# How to pick on which page to go after button back click in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I am developing `asp.net mvc2` application.I had a problem with back button after logout.That was fixed with example I found here.

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Now, I have a new problem.When I click logout and then back button in browser, I go on empty page.

How can I select on which page to redirect?

Comment: Take a look at [ASP.Net MVC 3 Redirect UnAuthorized User not to loginUrl](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7672104/580951).

Answer (score 0):

After logging-out, redirect to the main page:

```
Response.Redirect("/", true);
```

Or within a Controller Action:

```
return Redirect("/");
```