# Suppress browser authentication login dialog for a controller method that is using an [Authorize] action filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm in the process of creating an Intranet site using Windows Authentication.

Maybe I'm not going about this the best way, but I'm trying to load partial views via calling a controller method that has an Authorize action filter wrapped around it, so that only authorized individuals are able to see that portion of the page.  Say, for instance, I wanted to load administrator tools onto the page but only if the logged-in individual is an administrator.

So on the index.cshtml page I might have something like:

```
@Html.Action("LoadAdminTools","ControllerName")
```

The Controller would contain the code:

```
        [Authorize(Roles="Admins")]
        public ActionResult LoadAdminTools()
        {
            return PartialView("_AdminToolsPartialView");
        }
```

And then the partial view containing the admin controls (or whatever) would render to the page - **only** if the logged-in user was part of the *Admins* role.

The 'problem' I'm having is that if the person logged-in is not authorized to load the partial view, the browser pops up the login dialog asking for the user's credentials.  Closing the dialog without inputting any credentials causes the expected results - the partial view doesn't load while the rest of the page does. Cool, but annoying.  Input the incorrect credentials and you get a 401 error - also as expected.

If it helps: In IIS, Anonymous Authentication is *disabled*, Windows Authentication is *enabled*.
"Automatic logon with current user name and password" is selected in Internet Options under "Security Settings - Local Intranet Zone."

**My question is this**: Is there a way to use the [Authorize] action filter to load a partial view (or to do anything, really) without the browser asking the user to log in?  Just have it take the current logged-in credentials, check if they comply with the action filter, if they do, load the partial view, if not, then don't.  If there isn't, is there simply a better way of going about what I want to accomplish here?

**UPDATE**

---

Beautiful. I read the solution to the question you posted, Mystere Man, created a new class inside the Controller's folder called *IntranetAuthorizeAttribute.cs*, threw in the code:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class IntranetAuthorizeAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute
    {        
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new System.Web.Mvc.HttpStatusCodeResult(403);
            }
            else
            {
                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }
        }        
    }
```

Replaced the Authorize filter with my new IntranetAuthorize filter:

```
        [IntranetAuthorize(Roles="Admins")]
        public ActionResult LoadAdminTools()
        {
            return PartialView("_AdminToolsPartialView");
        }
```

And now it loads the page just fine with **no** browser login dialog - *with* the partial view when it's an *authorized* user, and *without* the partial view when it is *not an authorized* user =)

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, ASP.NET (and thus MVC) conflates Authorization and Authentication in may scenarios.

Check this question for a solution.

[Why does AuthorizeAttribute redirect to the login page for authentication and authorization failures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238437/why-does-authorizeattribute-redirect-to-the-login-page-for-authentication-and-au)