# Intercepting request if user is not in role

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 application with a custom membership provider.

I have a loginUrl specified in my web.config as follows:

```
<forms loginUrl="~/SSO/LogOn" timeout="86400" slidingExpiration="true"/>
```

I wondered how I can intercept this request when a user hits a page for which they don't have access rights so I can append something to this URL.

Comment: you want to intercept the request to the SSO based on the destination url in your site?

Comment: @YavgenyP That's more eloquently phrased, yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a Controller called SSO and an action method called LogOn, I think you just need to extend the AuthorizeAttribute:

```
public class AppendingAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{        
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        var url = new UrlHelper(context.RequestContext);
        var logonUrl = url.Action("LogOn", "SSO", new {appendedQueryStringParameter = "somevalue"});
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(logonUrl);
    }
}
```

Just annotate the controllers/action methods that require authorization with this attribute and it should redirect to a url which looks like:

> /SSO/LogOn?appendedQueryStringParameter=somevalue

Comment: That's really useful, thanks. Is there any way to override the existing Authorize attribute?

Comment: Apparently you can override it with the same name and MVC will use it instead of the default one: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/5844884/968301](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5844884/968301)