# ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API Authorization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am working on locking down various sections of an internal application's web api controller actions.  Currently, we are using Windows Authentication and a custom role provider.  When making ajax calls to the API, I would like to prevent the credentials prompt from showing up when the current user is not authorized to access the given api method.  We have a custom authorization filter for our MVC controller actions (NOT WEBAPI), but am not having much luck in preventing that prompt from showing up when making AJAX calls to a webapi action.

Is it possible to just deny/grant access via an authorize attribute and prevent that annoying login prompt from showing up?

Comment: please show your custom authorization filter code..

Comment: the custom authorization filter we are using is used only for MVC controller actions, not webapi.  Thus, it would have no impact for this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does AuthorizeAttribute redirect to the login page for authentication and authorization failures?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238437/why-does-authorizeattribute-redirect-to-the-login-page-for-authentication-and-au)