# MVC 4 Only Authorize user's should enter the certain page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, authorization

Okay i am developing some web application from the scratch. I have already made the custom login and registration pages using simple database from Tutorials [Login](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/482546/Creating-a-custom-user-login-form-with-NET-Csharp) and [Registration](http://dotnetawesome.blogspot.com/2014/03/how-to-create-user-registration-page-in-mvc4.html). Now here's my site GUI or API, lets say there are two programs **Program A** and **Program B**. Anyone can visit my site's **HOMEPAGE** and use **Program A** but only authenticated user can use **Program B** by LOGIN() i.e. Program B link will be visible to those users who are LOGGED-IN.

---

So i need help to make my Program B secure, i.e. its links will be visible to those who are LOGGED-IN. I want to clear one more thing that **Program A Link** and "Program B Link" both are coded on main **HomePage**, so u can't direct access **Program B** by just URL. I hope you get what I am trying to say ... HELP!!!
Below is my Login.cshtml code

```
  @model FYPFinalTest3.Models.UserLogin
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<h2>Login</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Login","Login", FormMethod.Post))
{
    //this  is for create form tag
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()          // this is for prevent CSRF attack
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    if (@ViewBag.Message != null)
    {
        <div style="border:1px solid red">
            @ViewBag.Message
        </div>
    }
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(a=>a.Username)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.Username)</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a=>a.Username)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(a=>a.Password)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.PasswordFor(a=>a.Password)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a=>a.Password)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}

@* This below line is for create javascript section *@

@section Scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Authorize attribute and can decorate your code as below :-

```
[Authorize]
public class ProgramB:Controller
   {

     public ActionResult Method1()
     {
       return View();
     }

     [Authorize]
     public ActionResult Method2()
     {
       return View();
     }
   }
```

So those users who are not logged in will be redirected to log in page.

For more details :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx

You can even create your own Custom Authorize attribute please have a look here :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707357(v=vs.91).aspx

Comment: Simply adding [authorization] is not doing the job. One more thing i don't understand how would this framework will know that user is authorized, because i am just using simple coding for matching username and password, nothing too complex.

Comment: I guess ur using form authentication..have you given authentication type in your web.config? can you post it here @WaqarAhmed?

Comment: Kindly review the link to the tutorial so that you will understand correctly what have i done, there is nothing to do with web.config in those steps. i have not changed anything in webconfig. <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

Comment: You will find that since you have enabled the forms authentication, you will be automatically redirected to the Login page "~/Account/Login" @WaqarAhmed...cyrrently what is happening when user is not logged in and you go direct on programB?

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238437/why-does-authorizeattribute-redirect-to-the-login-page-for-authentication-and-au?rq=1

Comment: That's the point, i have changed it to my loginPage, when i click Program B link, login page is displayed, after successful login, i have placed that ProgramB again in afterlogin page to check the authorizaion, when i click the Program B link again, again login page is displayed, like a circle loop. I think I know the reason which is i made my own registration and login page based on simple database. When i register i just takes data and saves into database, when i login it takes data and matches with data saved on database, SIMPLE.That's why it does not know the user is authorized. Help me:(

Comment: I guess you are missing something in your code..i would request you to go step by step instead of making any extra changes in starting..have a look here http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/looking-at-how-asp-net-mvc-authorize-interacts-with-asp-net-forms-authorization and make sample application step by step and once you understand then make modification @WaqarAhmed