# Microsoft.Owin.Security.IAuthenticationManager doesn't redirect to login page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, owin, asp.net-mvc-5.2, owin.security

I'm using `Microsoft.Owin.Security` in my application (ASP.NET MVC v 5.2.0 on .NET 4.5). But just the security part of `OWIN` nothing else. When a user wants to access to a protected URL, in local, the request get redirected to the login page. But when I publish the app on server, I get this window instead of redirecting:

[image]

my login and log-off methods are:

```
public void LogIn(long userId, string username, string email, bool persistent) {
    var claims = new List<Claim>{
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.IsPersistent, persistent.ToString())
    };
    var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    var ctx = HttpContext.Current.Request.GetOwinContext();
    var authenticationManager = ctx.Authentication;
    authenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties {
        IsPersistent = persistent
    }, id);
}

public void LogOut() {
    var ctx = HttpContext.Current.Request.GetOwinContext();
    var authenticationManager = ctx.Authentication;
    authenticationManager.SignOut();
}
```

and here is my startup:

```
public partial class Startup {
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/account/log-in/"),
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            CookieHttpOnly = true,
            CookieName = ".some-cookie-name",
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            LogoutPath = new PathString("/account/log-out/"),
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            ReturnUrlParameter = "continue"
        });
    }
}
```

I also have this line in `global.asax::Application_Start` method:

```
AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
```

and these configuration in *web.config*:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="None" />
  <httpModules>
    <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    <remove name="RoleManager" />
  </httpModules>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
    <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    <remove name="RoleManager" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

and finally I'm running the application on a **Windows 2008 R2** machine with **IIS 7.5**. Do you have any idea what should I do to make `OWIN` work correctly on my server, just like my local?

**UPDATE:** To be clear:

Assume I have these actions:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult AnonymousAction() { }

[Authorize]
public ActionResult UsersAction() { }
```

One for anonymous users, and another for logged-in users (which are well decorated with attributes). Anonymous users, can access `AnonymousAction` easily without any error or misbehavior. But when they (I mean Anonymous users) want to access `UsersAction`, instead of getting redirected to login page, they will see the window I mentioned above.

Comment: It appears that the webserver (IIS) might have anonymous access disabled for the website.

Comment: When this happens, what is the HTTP status code being received in a Fiddler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it was really simple. According to [@trailmax's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27595357/645167) (thanks to him), I realized that I should pay attention to the response's http-code. It was a `401 - Unauthorized` code. So, I asked myself why is that? Until I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5844884/645167). Then, the only thing I needed was creating the following attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class AuthorizeAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute {
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated) {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        } else {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Like Erik says, your IIS has incorrect settings, most likely that Authentication is not configured correctly.

Go to your IIS, select your site and choose Authentication section. It should look like this:
[image: Anonymous Authentication = Enabled]

Make sure your Anonymous Authentication is enabled and everything else is disabled.

Comment: Anonymous Authentication is enabled. Also, public pages in my application are accessible anonymously.

Comment: Not the answer, but +1. See my answer please.

Comment: Great, glad you sorted it. Not a trivial problem at all!

Answer (score 2):

Is it something to do with your login page URL in Startup? I notice this line;

```
LoginPath = new PathString("/account/log-in/")
```

is always directing to the root URL of the server. So if you're deploying to, say;

```
http://myserver.com/application1
```

then the login page will be

```
http://myserver.com/account/log-in/
```

but you probably mean

```
http://myserver.com/application1/account/log-in/
```

So you might want to try something like;

```
LoginPath = new PathString("~/account/log-in/")
```

with the `~` character. Same thing for the logoff url.

Comment: No, that's not a problem. This is the exact login page: `http://myserver.com/account/log-in/`