# Determine if bearer token has expired or is just authorized

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, owin, bearer-token

My angular application is making use of bearer tokens as outlined in the article series http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/.  I have followed the forked example to seamlessly refresh tokens when the access token has expired (via 401 http code).

My question is how can I determine if the bearer token is expired or just plain unauthorized based on the role determined?

For example, my web api method has the attribute [Authorize(Roles="Admin")].  When I make a call to that, I get back my 401 error, which is expected.  However, when my access token expires and I make another web api method call, it also returns a 401 error.  Heres my responseError handler in my interceptor:

```
        responseError: function (rejection) {
            var deferred = q.defer();
            if (rejection.status === 401) {
                var authService = $injector.get('authService');
                authService.refreshToken().then(function (response) {
                    _retryHttpRequest(rejection.config, deferred);
                }, function () {
                    authService.logOut();
                    $location.path('/dashboard');
                    deferred.reject(rejection);
                });
            } else {
                deferred.reject(rejection);
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

I was playing around with different things but basically, I'd like to refresh my token and resend my request when the access token has expired; however, I don't want to refresh my token if it truly is a denied request due to the role specified.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You should get back a 403 Forbidden when hitting a web api method has the attribute [Authorize(Roles="Admin")].  401 is for authentication.

Comment: Hmmm, after a little more digging, which I probably should've done in the first place, apparently the Web API Authorize attribute will always return 401 unauthorized for both authentication AND authorization.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As noted in my response to Cory Silva's comment, the Web API Authorize attribute will always return 401 unauthorized for both authentication AND authorization.

See article and thread below:

http://leastprivilege.com/2014/10/02/401-vs-403/

[Why does AuthorizeAttribute redirect to the login page for authentication and authorization failures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238437/why-does-authorizeattribute-redirect-to-the-login-page-for-authentication-and-au)

It looks like there are two options:

1. When I store the token retrieved from my authorization server in localStorage, I also store the token's expiration.  In the interceptor responseError function, I compare the stored token expiration with the current datetime.  If it's determined to be expired, refresh the token and resend the request.

   ```
   responseError: function (rejection) {
       var deferred = q.defer();

       if (rejection.status === 401) {
           var tokenExpired = false;
           var authData = localStorage.get('authorizationData');
           if (authData) {
               tokenExpired = moment().isAfter(authData.expiration);
           }

           if (tokenExpired) {
               var authService = auth;//$injector.get('authService');
               authService.refreshToken().then(function (response) {
                   _retryHttpRequest(rejection.config, deferred);
               }, function () {
                   authService.logOut();
                   $state.go('error');
                   deferred.reject(rejection);
               });
           }
           else {
               $state.go('error');
               deferred.reject(rejection);
           }
       } else {
           $state.go('error');
           deferred.reject(rejection);
       }
       return deferred.promise;
   }
   ```
2. Use the accepted answer in the stackoverflow thread I referenced above and create my own AuthorizeAttribute to determine token expiration vs. unauthorized access.

   ```
   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
   public class AuthorizeAttribute : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
   {
       protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
       {
           if (actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
           {
               actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
           }
           else
           {
               base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

I think I'm going to use option 2 so that the error codes a little clearer to the client.

Comment: I would use the second option too. The first option depends on the user computer time, so if the user change the time, it'll produce  incorrect behaviour.