# Infinite redirect with identity server v3 as a middleware for ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-5, identityserver3

I am using Identity Server v3 as my OWIN middlerware with an ASP.NET MVC application. On my production server I am getting into infinite loop when user is trying to login.

After user is successfully authenticated, I can see that the request is redirected back to the app and immediately redirected back to identity server and the loop continues.

This happens only on my prod server when I am trying to host the application inside "Default Web Site". Default Web Site is using default ports for http and https. If I host my application as a separate website or as an application inside another website, everything works fine.

My default web site has applications configured to use both Classic and Integrated pipeline modes. I tried to replicate this scenario just to make sure I am not missing something and I have no problems.

I have verified to make sure all other Identity Server configurations are correct. Can anybody throw an idea on what else I can verify?

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am not sure if this is infrastructure problem. This can be something I am missing Identity Server Configuration with in my application. I wanted to know where I am going wrong.

Comment: hi, any updates as why it was getting into an infinte loop on the production servers?I am facing a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

Please try downgrading ***Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect*** from 3.0.1 to 3.0.0.

**EDIT:**

An other reason, it can be stucked with Authorize 401. If so, this link can help better: [Why does AuthorizeAttribute redirect to the login page for authentication and authorization failures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238437/why-does-authorizeattribute-redirect-to-the-login-page-for-authentication-and-au)