# How to solve 'Authorize' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Web.Mvc.Authorizeattribute' and 'ProjectDefaultNamespace'?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

As following to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5844884) answer I have created an `AuthorizeAttribute` class in my projects default namespace. So that the compiler will automatically pick it up instead of MVC's standard one. But it picks `System.Web.Mvc.Authorizeattribute`.

If I include my projects namespace, which is `using TestIdentitySample;` then the following error was shown

```
  'Authorize' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Web.Mvc.Authorizeattribute' and 'ProjectDefaultNamespace'
```

- Please be noted that I do not want to use **fully qualified name** or **namespace alias** or **other Custome Attributes name**.

> My AuthorizeAttribute Class

```
namespace TestIdentitySample
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class AuthorizeAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new System.Web.Mvc.HttpStatusCodeResult((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
            }
            else
            {
                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I just want that the compiler will automatically pick it up instead of MVC's standard one if it is possible. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It would so long as you have no references at all to `System.Web.Mvc` in the code (but that would be highly unlikely since you would want to use that on a `Controller`), so just change the name of the attribute, or use the fully qualified name.

Comment: Got your point.

Comment: *"Please be noted that I do not want to use fully qualified name or namespace alias or other Custome Attributes name."* These are your options. What's wrong with them?

Answer (score 4):

You should rethink your approach of creating your own attribute *with the same name*. This is problematic for two reasons:

1. Readers of your code might think it's the built-in attribute and not your own. They might get a misconception about what your code does. This is especially important for the `AuthorizeAttribute`, since security is a usually a critical issue in a web application
2. You could run into naming conflicts. That's exactly what happended here.

You can resolve your issue in different ways:

**Rename your attribute**

A good solution - and the solution that I would recommend - would be to simply rename your custom attribute so that it's clear that it is yours and the naming conflict gets resolved.

**Specify the namespace explicitly**

If you want to keep the same name of the attribute, you can resolve the naming conflict by explicitly specifying your own namespace:

```
[ProjectDefaultNamespace.Authorize]
```

**Use a namespace alias**

You can also specify a namespace alias in your `using` list:

```
using MyAuthorizeAttribute = ProjectDefaultNamespace.AuthorizeAttribute;
```

And then apply it like:

```
[MyAuthorizeAttribute]
```

But then again, why not just giving it your own custom name? It will look the same in code, just without the additional complication of the alias.

Comment: @Safe, thanks for your ans, it makes sense. I have gone through these solutions already. I just wanted to avoid them so that the other programmers who are used to use '[Authorize(Roles = "foo")] did not think about the new Custome Authorize name or about the new additional namespace.

Comment: @ramzanali: If you create your own attribute, developers *will*  have to think about that. Since there is no way around it, clarifying that with your own name, rather **helps** them with that. It's worse to keep developers in the dark by creating hidden functionalities. They have to understand the code that they're writing 100%. Adding hidden features doesn't help with that.